# UITableViewAutomaticDimension not setting correct height with emoji characters in the UILabel of UITableviewCell

Tags: uitableview, emoji, heightforrowatindexpath

I am using UITableViewAutomaticDimension for dynamic height of cells of a UITableview. Everything works fine when I set plain text in the label inside the UITableviewCell.

Problem occurs with the cell height when I set plain text along with emoji characters in the label. The cell height do increase dynamically but the height is wrong due to emoji characters. I think UITableview may be considering the unicode as a text instead of emoji icon hence it returns only plain text height.

In my case label's x origin is also dynamic.

Please see the below screen shots for the problem occurring,

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Remove UITableViewAutomaticDimension, calculate height of label dynamically by below given methods and manage cell height accordingly.

//--- Calculate Height Of String ---//

```
+(CGFloat)textHeight:(NSString*)text withFont:(UIFont*)font andMaxWidth:(CGFloat)maxWidth 
{
     CGFloat maxHeight = 99999;
     CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(maxWidth,maxHeight);
     NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font};
     CGRect expectedLabelSize = [text boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:attributes context:nil];
     return expectedLabelSize.size.height;
}
```

Comment: It's Working. Thanks!!